# Is it considered more useful to answer with pseudo-code or code?

Tags: discussion, code

I'm not a big fan of spoon-feeding but I'm aware sometimes you just have to provide code in order to clarify a point.

But is it more useful in the long run to provide pseudo-code and then comment on OP's edited code or just give him an example and call it a day?

Comment: ... code will always be better than pseudo code.

Comment: @TinyGiant ... unless it isn't. The beauty of pseudo-code is all the detaills one can ignore.

Comment: I believe pseudo-code allows for some level of abstraction you sometimes cannot exemplify with code.

Comment: It depends.  What's more important to the question?  Correct runnable code, or an idea/plan?

Comment: Details like language constraints? @Deduplicator

Comment: @ryanyuyu Better programmers. Always.

Comment: @TinyGiant: That too, if they aren't important.

Comment: @Onilol that was not one of my options.  Let me rephrase.  Does the question asker seem to need more guidance on syntactically correct code (for example they are new to the language/framework), or just guidance in an algorithm where pseudocode is fine?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I guess both options could be answered both ways. You can exemplify a seemingly complex code with a pseudo-code or you can provide an alternative with code. But which one do you think is better ?

Comment: @Onilol It depends on the OP.  If they want code, give them code.  For example, if their question is I tried [code] but it fail because [reason] give them code.  If their question is this is [my goal] and I've started with [current code] but I'm stuck, then pseudo code (or boilerplate code) might be more appropriate.  I personally prefer code in most situations.

Answer (score 5):

## Both. And neither.

You want your answer to focus on the real problem, not on any side-issues.

And in many situations, real code is so verbose, rigid and thorny the mechanics of the chosen language and other side-issues obscure the important parts.

By all means, if those mechanics and/or side-issues are important, or there's nothing to be gained by going for pseudo-code (or simply omitting all code), use real code.

Also, some answers benefit from adding real code applying the explanation(s) at the end (for example as a hidden stack snippet, if for websites).

Comment: So you don't mind giving a 'straight to the face' answer instead of helping the OP think by itself the best approach ? This might sound offending or agressive but it's not , ok ? <3

Comment: Well, the most important part, especially in the long run (or for any worthy asker) is the explanation (is that a staraight answer? Maybe.). Whether to support that with code, pseudo-code, neither or both, that depends. And generally SO isn't really suited for tutoring, so if that's needed for the OP, the question is (generally) a loss from the start.

Comment: Don't you think it exists a thin line between an explanation and a "short" tutoring?

Comment: @Onilol Separate the question from the person who asked the OP. the question is by the community, for the community. The answer should be too. In the case of the javascript tag, i find it far more useful to provide javascript over pseudo code simply because the javascript can be executed.

Comment: @KevinB Imagine this scenario. I make you ( the community ) a javascript question and you ( yes, you ) answer with a very complex solution that gets the job done. Beautiful ! You gave me an aswer that resolved my problem but now I got another problem since I can't improve that code because I have no idea on how it works ( In this example a beginner OP ). You see the kind of things that could happen ?

Comment: Right, but that's not my problem, that's a question that should be asked as another question. That's no different than the user having an issue with their own code.